# laravel belongsToMany Filter

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have three tables as below:

### users

id|name|username|password

### roles

id|name

### users_roles

id|user_id|role_id

These tables communicate via belongsToMany. 
I would like to find a way to select all data in “users” table except ones that their user value of "role_id" is 5 in table “users_roles”.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `whereDoesntHave()` to select models that don't have a related model meeting certain criteria:

```
$users = User::whereDoesntHave('roles', function($q){
    $q->where('role_id', 5);
})->get();
```

Comment: I think `'role_id'` should be `'id'` because `roles` has `id` not `role_id`

Comment: @MTVS Both works. `role_id` is the column from the pivot table.

Comment: How can I transmit it to Eager Loading

Comment: @NavidSedehi If you want to eager load `roles` just add `with('roles')` anywhere in the query. `User::with('roles')->whereDoesntHave(...)->get()`

Answer (score 2):

Use Laravel's Query Builder:

```
<?php
$users = DB::table('users')
    ->leftJoin('users_roles', 'user.id', '=', 'users_roles.user_id')
    ->where('users_roles.role_id', '!=', 5)
    ->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries

Or using Eloquent directly:

```
<?php
$users = User::whereHas('users_roles', function($q)
{
    $q->where('role_id', '!=', 5);

})->get();
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: sql has not != operator

Comment: @Morilog MySQL does: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_not-equal

Comment: the problem is: 
users who doesn't have role are not displayed. how we can display them?

Comment: @Morilog Actually the operator is intended for laravel query builder and both `<>` and `!=` notations are supported

Comment: @NavidSedehi Which version did you try? Now that you mention that, I think the Query Builder way is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$users = User::whereHas('roles', function($query) {
  $query->where('id', '<>', 5);
})
->orHas('roles','<', 1)
->get();
```

Comment: While this code sample may possibly answer the question, it would be preferable to include some essential explanation to your answer. As it stands now this answer adds little to no value for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct answer is:

```
    User::whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
        $query->whereId(5)
    }, '=', 0)->get();
```

This code should send a query that checks if the `role` with `id=5` is related to the `user` or not.

### Edit

While I think this should work but the @lukasgeiter answer is preferable.

In the end both methods use the `has()` to count the related models by using a subquery in the `db query where clause` but when you use the `whereDoesntHave()` it specifies the operator `<` and the count `1` itself.

You can `var_dump(DB::getQueryLog())` in `App::after()`'s callback to see the actual query.