# Lumen/Laravel Eloquent - filter by attribute in pivot table

Tags: eloquent, lumen

I have three tables, `users`, `talents` and `user_talent` as pivot table and I am trying to filter users based on their talents. The relations are that users can have multiple talents and talents can be assigned to multiple users.

**Relations:**

```
public function talents() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Talent');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User');
}
```

This is working well. Now I am trying to filter the users based on the talent IDs but I am failing in doing that.

**With:**
Talent model does not use $with, while User does:

```
protected $with = [
    'talents'
];
```

**Filter** (please note that I removed other filters and paginator):

```
public function getAllModelsWithFilters(Request $request) {
    $model = User::query();
        $sortColumn = 'full_name';
        $sortDir = 'orderBy';

    if ($request->has('talents')) {
        $ids = [];
        $array = explode(',', $request->query('talents')); // provided as string: 1,2,3,6
        foreach($array as $arr) {
            $res = (int) $arr;
            if (!empty($res)) {
                $ids[] = $res;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($ids)) {
            $model->with([
                'talents' => function ($q) use ($ids) {
                    $q->whereIn('talents.id', $ids);
                }
            ]);
        }
    }

    return CustomResponse::success([
        'data' => $model->{$sortDir}($sortColumn)->get()
    ]);
}
```

**Result**

Result is that I am getting back all users, even those with no talents assigned.

**Expected results**

A collection of users that are filtered based on talents.

Using Lumen v7.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Got answer here: [laravel belongsToMany Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327703/laravel-belongstomany-filter)

Changed above code to:

```
if ($request->has('talents')) {
    $ids = [];
    $array = explode(',', $request->query('talents')); // provided as string: 1,2,3,6
    foreach($array as $arr) {
        $res = (int) $arr;
        if (!empty($res)) {
            $ids[] = $res;
        }
    }
    if (!empty($ids)) {
        $model->whereHas('talents', function($q) use ($ids) {
            $q->whereIn('talents.id', $ids);
        });
    }
}
```